# MS Access Passthrough query does not return records

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I send a passthrough query from MS Access to SQL Server but it does not return the expected record(s).

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (AColumn VARCHAR(max))
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES('Hello world')
SELECT * FROM @Table
```

I get an error (translated):

> Passthrough query property ReturnRecords is set to True but the query did not return any record

But if I run exactly the same query in SSMS, it returns the expected answer

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try adding `SET NOCOUNT ON` as the first statement in the batch.

Comment: It works! Thank you! Why is that needed?

Comment: The command line processor spits out "messages" that get mixed in with what the query/t-sql tries to return. In SSMS, click on the messages tab (in your screen shot) - you see (1 row affected) and possible other messages.  So those messages also get returned - but they are not records. Setting NO COUNT  ON suppresses "some" of the messages.